# Python - Building dataframe for plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Below is a code snippet that goes and gets a csv which was unzipped from here: https://github.com/sstangl/openpowerlifting-static/raw/gh-pages/openpowerlifting-latest.zip into my JupyterLab. I am trying to plot all the gender ratios for each year from 1974 - 2019. I am new to python and don't understand how I can use the get_gender_ratios method to build a dataframe so that I have 2 rows(Male, Female) and the columns will be the years that would show the ratio for each Male and Female. Some years only have Males, most have both. I know I need to do some sort of concatenation to the dataframe but just cant figure out the syntax to build it. I have a while loop below that shows how to use the method to get the gender ratios but storing that info into the dataframe is my problem. Once I get the new dataframe built, I am suppose to transpose the data so I can just do a plot to see how the gender ratios changed over the years. Not real sure how to transpose it. I know how to plot a dataframe but building the dataframe from this method is where I am stuck. I have done all the research to try and see how I can build this and havent had any luck. Any help is appreciated. Code snippet below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./openpowerlifting-2019-11-20/openpowerlifting-2019-11-20.csv", low_memory=False)

def get_gender_ratios(df,year):
   return df.query('Date>"{}-01-01" & Date<"{}-01-01"'.format(year, year+1)).loc[:, 
   ['Sex']].squeeze().value_counts() \
   / df.query('Date>"{}-01-01" & Date<"{}-01-01"'.format(year, year+1)).loc[:,['Sex']].shape[0]


count = 1974
while (count < 2019):
   print(count)
   print(get_gender_ratios(df,count))
   count = count + 1
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you done any research, read any guides or documentation?

Comment: I would rather create column with only year and use it with `groupby("Year")` or `groupby("Year", "Sex")`and then calculate for every. it should give results in one dataframe.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - What else is there to research? I have provided the code that shows what I have tried.

Comment: Groupby may be helpful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html and seaborn is great for plotting categorical data where columns in your dataframe indicate categories: https://seaborn.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0):

First you can create column with `Year` and then it is easier to filter or group rows

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[:4]
```

First I was thinking about grouping by `Year` and `Sex` to count items

```
groups = df.groupby(['Year', 'Sex'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['Count'] = groups['Sex'].count()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

print(df2.head(20))
```

but it doesn't create rows when there is no `Females` and I thing it would need more work to add these rows.

So I grouped by `Year` and filtered `Male` and `Female` in every group to count them

```
groups = df.groupby(['Year'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Sex', 'Count', 'Ratio'])

for year, data in groups:
    M = len(data[ data['Sex'] == 'M' ])
    F = len(data[ data['Sex'] == 'F' ])

    df2 = df2.append([
        {'Year': year, 'Sex': 'M', 'Count': M, 'Ratio': M/(F+M)},
        {'Year': year, 'Sex': 'F', 'Count': F, 'Ratio': F/(F+M)}
    ], ignore_index=True)

print(df2.head(20))
```

This way I get zero when there is no `Females`

```
    Year Sex Count  Ratio
0   1964   M    21    1.0
1   1964   F     0    0.0
2   1965   M    45    1.0
3   1965   F     0    0.0
4   1966   M    71    1.0
5   1966   F     0    0.0
6   1967   M    72    1.0
7   1967   F     0    0.0
8   1968   M    80    1.0
9   1968   F     0    0.0
10  1969   M    57    1.0
11  1969   F     0    0.0
12  1970   M    94    1.0
13  1970   F     0    0.0
14  1971   M   151    1.0
15  1971   F     0    0.0
16  1972   M   211    1.0
17  1972   F     0    0.0
18  1973   M   143    1.0
19  1973   F     0    0.0
```

---

More problems I had to plot `Males` and `Females` on one plot

```
ax = plt.gca()
df2[ df2['Sex'] == 'M' ].plot('Year', 'Ratio', kind='bar', label='M', color='red',  ax=ax, position=0)
df2[ df2['Sex'] == 'F' ].plot('Year', 'Ratio', kind='bar', label='F', color='green', ax=ax, position=1)
plt.show()
```

Maybe you find better way to do this.

### [image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('openpowerlifting-2019-11-20.csv', low_memory=False) # ,headers=None, sep=';'
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[:4]

groups = df.groupby(['Year'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Sex', 'Count', 'Ratio'])
for year, data in groups:
    M = len(data[ data['Sex'] == 'M' ])
    F = len(data[ data['Sex'] == 'F' ])

    df2 = df2.append([
        {'Year': year, 'Sex': 'M', 'Count': M, 'Ratio': M/(F+M)},
        {'Year': year, 'Sex': 'F', 'Count': F, 'Ratio': F/(F+M)}
    ], ignore_index=True)

print(df2.head(20))

ax = plt.gca()
df2[ df2['Sex'] == 'M' ].plot('Year', 'Ratio', kind='bar', label='M', color='red',  ax=ax, position=0)
df2[ df2['Sex'] == 'F' ].plot('Year', 'Ratio', kind='bar', label='F', color='green', ax=ax, position=1)
plt.show()
```